# how to filter objects in Django

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class CampaignType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    campaign_type = models.ForeignKey(CampaignType)
```

Target to achieve:

```
for i in CampaignType.objects.all()
    for j in Campaign.objects.filter(name=i.name)
        print j.name
```

How can i achieve the above 'nested for' in a DJANGO TEMPLATE ?
I basically want to categorize the Campaigns based on Types.
please help.

Comment: are you wanting to separate campaigns by campaign type in your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to filter manually, you should just be using the reverse relationship accessors that Django provides for you automatically.

```
{% for campaigntype in campaigntypes %}
    {% for campaign in campaigntype.campaign_set.all %}
        {{ campaign.name }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yup that worked..Thanks...I totally forgot abt the _set

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to select Campaigns with select_related so all CampaignTypes are also available by single query.

Use regroup template tag in the template to display Campaigns grouped by CampaignType.

View

```
campaigns = Campaign.objects.all().select_related ()
```

Template

```
{% regroup campaigns by campaign_type as campaign_list %}

<ul>
    {% for campaign in campaign_list %}
        <li>{{ campaign.grouper.name }}
            <ul>
                {% for item in campaign.list %}
                    <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by setting a list of lists in a context variable, in which each element of list will be a list of all campaigns of one campaign-type.

To set such variable for use in template, use `get_context_data()` in your view.

See here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data

-- Assuming you set that in variable `campaign_types_list`, and you want to render in the format `campaign_type -> campaign` then in your template you'll do something like this-

```
{% for campaigns_in_campaign_type in campaign_type_list %}
    {% for campaign in campaigns_in_campaign_type %}
        {{ campaign.campaign_type}} -> {{ campaign }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

### EDIT

for format given in your comment, you can do following -

```
{% for campaigns_in_campaign_type in campaign_type_list %}
    {% for campaign in campaigns_in_campaign_type %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            {{ campaign.campaign_type}}
        {% endif %}
        {{ campaign }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, please go through [django template-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/)

Comment: Actually i want to print it like  
Campaign_type1  
   campaign1  
   campaign2  
Camapign_type2  
   campaign1  
   campaign2

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, in Django it's generally frowned upon to allow a lot of logic, especially logic that queries the database, to be executed in the template logic.

For achieving what you want to achieve, I feel it would be best to collect your results in a well defined python container, and then pass the container to the template to render.

Also, If you're trying to get a mapping of category_type to all categories, your logic seems to be a bit mushy.

Try something like this:

```
collect = []
for camp_type in CampaignType.objects.all()
    collect.append((camp_type, camp_type.campaign_set.all()))
```

Then try to write a simple nested for loop

```
{% for holder in collect %}
  <h1> {{ holder.0 }} </h1>
  {% for category in holder.1 %}
  <p>{{ category }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I wonder if the OP even tried the answer before downvoting it. If this hasn't solved your problem, could you please let me know what issues did you face? Also, do look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/performance/#work-at-the-appropriate-level and stop querying the db at the template level.